# wp get unique and returning customers SQL Query

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

```
 SELECT
        pm.meta_value AS customer_id,
        CASE
            WHEN pm.meta_value IN (
                SELECT pm.meta_value
                FROM biotech_posts p
                JOIN biotech_postmeta pm ON p.ID = pm.post_id AND pm.meta_key = '_customer_user'
                WHERE p.post_type = 'shop_order'
                AND p.post_date < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
            ) THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END AS is_new
    FROM
        biotech_posts p
    JOIN
        biotech_postmeta pm ON p.ID = pm.post_id AND pm.meta_key = '_customer_user'
    WHERE
        p.post_type = 'shop_order'
        AND p.post_date >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
```

I am trying to get unique and returning users but my query got stuck every time. it takes too much time to execute. after that, it returns the error

> Error in processing request
> Error code: 500
> Error text: Internal Server Error (rejected)
> It seems that the connection to the server has been lost. Please check your network connectivity and server status

Note I am executing it on my local computer

Comment: trying to understand the meaning of your query: if a customer (determined by its ID) has only one order inside the "shop_order" table (in the last year) then it is considered new, otherwise, if there's more than one order for a customer ID, it's considered returning?

Comment: yes, that's correct. but the issue is query does not return anything. it got stuck

Comment: any particular reason to use an SQL query, or you can approach it using woocommerce APIs?

Comment: I have only a database

Comment: no access to the theme's functions file?

Comment: yes i don't have access to theme files